# Seeking reasoning and verification that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2 (n+1)})^r$ diverges for $0<r<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Seeking reasoning and verification that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2 (n+1)}\right)^r$$ diverges for $0<r<1$.

Referring to a thread from 2016:

[Is there a series satisfies $a_n>0,\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum a_n^{r}$ diverges for all $0\leq r<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735465/is-there-a-series-satisfies-a-n0-sum-a-n-converges-but-sum-a-nr-diverg)

I verified that the sum converges for $r=1$ using the integral test, but am having a difficult time verifying its divergence for $0<r<1$.

My apologies if this is obvious. My available resources and textbooks lack clarity on the subject.

Comment: You could try to use the integral test. Alternatively you could try the comparison test, if you can show that $\ln^{2r}(n+1)$ is at most $(n+1)^{1-r}$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then you can compare the series to the harmonic series.

Comment: Cauchy Condensation test works nicely here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is needed is that,
for $0 < c < 1$,
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^c}
=0
$.

This has been proved here many times,
often by me,
so I will leave this to you.

Since
$0 < r < 1$,
let
$c = \dfrac{1-r}{2}
$
so $0 < c < 1$,
$r=1-2c$,
and $c < 1-r$.

Then,
writing $n$ for
$n+1$
since it doesn't matter,
we want to show that
$(n \ln^2(n))^r
\lt n^s$
for some
$0 < s < 1$,
since
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^s}$
diverges.

$\begin{array}\\
(n \ln^2(n))^r
&=(n \ln^2(n))^{1-2c}\\
&=n^{1-2c} \ln^{2(1-2c)}(n)\\
&\lt n^{1-2c} \ln^{2}(n)\\
&\lt n^{1-c} n^{-c}\ln^{2}(n)\\
&\lt n^{1-c} \dfrac{\ln^{2}(n)}{n^c}\\
&\lt n^{1-c}
\qquad\text{for large enough }n\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{(n \ln^2(n))^r}
&\gt \dfrac1{n^{1-c}}
\qquad\text{for large enough }n\\
\end{array}
$

and this sum of this diverges.

No te that this works for
$\dfrac1{(n \ln^b(n))^r}$
for any $b > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Claim 1: For any $\beta\in(0,\infty)$, there exists $n_{0}$ such
that $\ln n\leq n^{\beta}$ whenever $n\geq n_{0}$.

Proof: Let $\beta\in(0,\infty)$ be given. By L Hospital rule,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{\beta}}\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\beta x^{\beta-1}}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\beta}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\beta}}\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, there exists $x_{0}$ such that $\frac{\ln x}{x^{\beta}}<\frac{1}{2}$
whenever $x\geq x_{0}$. In particular, $\ln n\leq n^{\beta}$ whenever
$n\in\mathbb{N}\cap(x_{0},\infty)$.

---

For your problem: Let $r\in(0,1)$ be given. Choose $\beta\in(0,\frac{1-r}{2r})$.
Choose $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\ln n\leq n^{\beta}$ whenever
$n\geq n_{0}$. Denote $\alpha=(2\beta+1)r$. Note that $0<\alpha<1$.

For $n\geq n_{0}$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & n^{r}\left(\ln n\right)^{2r}\\
 & \leq & n^{r}\cdot\left(n^{\beta}\right)^{2r}\\
 & = & n^{(2\beta+1)r}\\
 & = & n^{\alpha}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\ln^{2}n}\right)^{r}\\
 & \geq & \sum_{n=n_{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\ln^{2}n}\right)^{r}$
diverges.

Answer (score 1):

We can show given series diverges using [Bertrand's test of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671933/proof-of-bertrand-test-of-convergence). From the series, $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)ln^2(n+1)}$ Now let's look at the following limit, where $0<r<1$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2(n+1)}\right)^r}{\left(\frac{1}{(n+2)\ln^2(n+2)}\right)^r}-1\right)-1\right)\ln{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(n\left(\left(\frac{(n+2)ln^2(n+2)}{(n+1)ln^2(n+1)}\right)^r-1\right)-1\right)\ln{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{((n(1-1)-1)\ln n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{(-\ln{n})}=-\infty<1$$

Thus, using the Bertrand's test of convergence we can conclude that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2 (n+1)}\right)^r$ diverges for $0< r<1$. You can easily show that it also diverges for all $r\le0$, meaning the series diverges for all $r<1$.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment section we can conveniently use *[Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)*. We write the series as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln^2(n+1)}\right)^r=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\right)^r \tag{1}
\end{align*}

> According to *Cauchy's condenation test* the right-hand side of (1) converges iff the following series converges. Given $0<r<1$, we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{2^n\left(\frac{1}{2^n\ln^2\left(2^n\right)}\right)^r}
> &=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{n(1-r)}\frac{1}{\left(\ln(2^n)\right)^{2r}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{n(1-r)}\frac{1}{\left(n\ln (2)\right)^{2r}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\left(\ln (2)\right)^{2r}}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{n(1-r)}\frac{1}{n^{2r}}\to\infty}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> Since (2) diverges, the divergence of (1) follows.